# Unresolved External Symbol while creating an object

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2001

I am trying to run a main.cpp which access 3 different classes.  For some reason, I am getting a unresolved external symbol error. From what I've seen online, its clearly a linking error somewhere, but I cannot find it.  I've listed the error below, but it's got a lot of info in it and im having trouble finding out exactly what it means.

The error: main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AtpReader::AtpReader(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (??0AtpReader@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

My code is:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "atlasobject.h"
#include "atp.h"
#include "atpreader.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    AtpReader reader("E:/doc.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

AtpReader.h:

```
#ifndef ATPREADER_H
#define ATPREADER_H
#include "atp.h"

class AtpReader
{
public:
    AtpReader();
    AtpReader(string filename);

    void atpReadHeader();
    void atpRead();
    string decryptLine(string line);

    ATP readerATP;

private:
    string file;
};
#endif // ATPREADER_H
```

atp.h:

```
#ifndef ATP_H
#define ATP_H
#include "atlasobject.h"
#include "vector"

struct Image{
    string Dim;
    string Vox;
    string Ori;
    char* data;
};

class ATP
{
public:
    ATP();
    vector<AtlasObject> listOfMaps;

private:
    Image referenceImage;
};
#endif // ATP_H
```

and AtlasObject.h:

```
#ifndef ATLASOBJECT_H
#define ATLASOBJECT_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class AtlasObject{

public:
    //virtual void create();
    AtlasObject();

    void set_uid(string id);
    void set_label(string l);
    void set_offset(string o);
    void set_mapInfo(string info);
    void set_data(char* inData);
    void set_isEncrypted(int encrypted);

    string get_uid();
    string get_label();
    string get_offset();
    string get_mapInfo();
    char* get_data();
    int get_isEncrypted();

protected:
    string uid;
    string label;
    string offset;
    string mapInfo;
    char *data;
    int isEncrypted;
};
#endif // ATLASOBJECT_H
```

my AtpReader.cpp is:

```
#include "atpreader.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>

AtpReader::AtpReader()
{
    printf("AtpReader()\n");
}

AtpReader::AtpReader(string filename)
{
    printf("AtpReader(%s)\n",filename.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you did not include AtpReader.h in AtpReader.cpp, but probably you just missed it when you made copy/paste, to insert it here, because if you didn't really include it, the error would have been different. Also, I see you're including in your main.cpp  both "atlasobject.h"
and "atp.h" and you don't really need that.

Later edit: Your problem is in the atp.h...you constructor is declared but never defined. Do this: ATP(){};

Comment: I edited the question to include AtpReader.h include statements, thank you.  And yes, I know I have some redundancy, I just didn't want to leave anything out when including files since i knew this was a problem with linking.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to point that out. Check, I have edited my answer, I think I have the answer to your problem.

Comment: I do have an atp.cpp file that consists of

#include "atp.h"

    ATP::ATP()
    {
    }

is that not enough? I just didn't include it in the question because it was so basic.

Comment: And did you add everything (all the files) to the project?

Comment: I believe so.  All the files are listed in my debug folder and in my .pro file I have SOURCES += main.cpp \ atlasobject.cpp \ atp.cpp \ atpreader.cpp\ and HEADERS += \atlasobject.h \ atp.h \ atpreader.h

Comment: OK, so I still think you did not add everything to the project. I was curios, I made a project (I am using Visual Studio 2008, but I don't think it really matters), I've added all the files (the one you've mentioned) and I can compile it. No errors. If I remove AtpReader.cpp from the project, I get the same error that you pointed out...

Comment: Fantastic, somehow my debug/release folders were plcaes apart from my .h/.cpp files.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `g++` in linux terminal
make the object files of each of the source codes and then link the object files and run the executable

```
g++ -c atp.cpp AtpReader.cpp AtlasObject.cpp
g++ -o exe atp.o AtpReader.o AtlasObject.o
./exe
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  Where do I do that? I'm writing my code in Qt Creator, do I use the command line for that?

Comment: Yes...using linux terminal

Comment: Sorry, I am on windows, I don't have a linux terminal (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

`AtpReader.cpp` is not getting built or the its object file is not getting linked to final executable. Check if AtpReader.obj/.o is created in build directory.

Comment: In my build directory, I see an atlasobject.obj and a main.obj, no other .obj files.  How do I make sure it gets built?

Comment: Check your `.pro` project file , are you sure you have `SOURCES += main.cpp \ atlasobject.cpp \ atp.cpp \ atpreader.cpp` without an extra `\\` at the end?

Comment: My file has `SOURCES += main.cpp \ atlasobject.cpp \ atp.cpp \ atpreader.cpp HEADERS += \ atlasobject.h \ atp.h \ aptreader.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the linker error you are getting and assuming that this is some of your actual code. Since I can't see any function inlining, global constants or variables being used out of scope I think the problem is located in the AtpReader.cpp, are you missing an `#include AtpReader.h` there?

> With just a function prototype, the compiler can continue without error, but the linker cannot resolve a call to an address because there is no function code or variable space reserved. You will not see this error until you create a call to the function that the linker must resolve.

Comment: I added in the rest of my atpreader.cpp file to the question.  As far as I can see I am not missing any includes.  Most of the ones I have in there are for future use, but the atpreader.h should be included the very first thing.

Comment: You are sure it is in lower case?

Comment: All of the h and cpp files are lowercase.  The classes are capitalized though.  So I include "atpreader" but create an AtpReader object.